# convert Nested array into mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to generate a mysql insert query with this array , where the column name are the field_name & values are field_values. i tried using implode, here its nested array & troubling me lot.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => Date
                [field_value] => 01/02/2013
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => Time
                [field_value] => 03:20 PM
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => submitted_lat
                [field_value] => 13.06114
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => submitted_long
                [field_value] => 80.2371547
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => submitted_on
                [field_value] => 2013-02-01 15:20:10
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => submitted_by
                [field_value] => superadmin@gmail.com
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [field_name] => pdf
                [field_value] =>
            )

    )
```

Comment: what is the name of your table?

Comment: @SankalpMishra Does that matters?

Comment: @Ravi no, i just ran into something

Comment: Hopefully the answers you get should convert it into a prepared statement rather than a basic MySQL statement

Comment: @MarkBaker : That's what I advise to do in my answer, but I'm familiar with only MySQLi which requires the type of the column to bind the values properly which the array does not provide.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` SET ";
$sql_fields='';

foreach($array_name as $k=>$v){
    $sql_fields .= "`".$v['field_name']."`='".$v['field_value']."', ";
}

$sql_fields = substr($sql_fields,0,-2);
$sql .= $sql_fields;
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approch would be this :

```
$query = 'insert into table ';
foreach($inputs as $input) {
  $query .= ' '.$input['field_name'].' = '.$input['field_value']; 
}
echo $query;
```

Comment: See $query =  'insert into table where'

Comment: What I mean is: there is no "where" clause in MySQL insert statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$fields=array();
$values=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
   $fields[]=$array[$i]['field_name'];
   $values[]=$array[$i]['field_value'];
}

if(count($array) > 0)
{
   $query="Insert into tablename (".implode(",", $fields).") values (".implode(",", $values).")";
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure that your values are correct and protected to avoid SQL Injection. Building dynamically your own SQL query and inserting directly in your database is not safe.

Anyway you can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do something like this:

```
$arr = array(array("name" => "column1", "value" => "value1"),
             array("name" => "column2", "value" => "value2"),
             array("name" => "column3", "value" => "value3"));

$columns = array_map(function($item) { return $item['name'];}, $arr);
$values = array_map(function($item) { return "'". $item['value'] . "'";}, $arr);


$columnsList = implode(',', $columns);
$valuesList = implode(',', $values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable($columnsList) VALUES ($valuesList)";
```

EDIT: As said in introduction this would not be safe and it would be better to use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). But you would also need to know the type of the column you want to insert into.